# CCDA to FHIR xml

Tags: mirth, hl7-fhir, c-cda

Is it Possible to convert a complete CCDA xml to a FHIR based xml? I would like to convert an complete CCDA xml to a FHIR compatible XML through Mirthconnect interface. 
I like to have sample messages that shows how a complete CCDA is been transformed to FHIR based XML, I googled and ended up with no answers. It would be great if you guys help me.

Comment: The answer is Yes, it's possible. If you are asking for the source code to copy-paste, the answer is No because FHIR is in DSTU2 and it's not too many (shared) implementations available yet.

Comment: I'm concerned about the message format actually. I went through FHIR official site and stumbled on message formats. For a Particular section of CCDA for (eg: PatientDemographics), a equivalent separate FHIR message format as either (patient.xml/patient.json) is available, and there are several other FHIR messages available like medications, immunizations etc. But like CCDA do we have a consolidated FHIR message for a patient?, including all the sections in CCDA?

Comment: To begin with, those are resources, not messages. And CCDA is a number of document templates. Because of that, as I mentioned earlier, there is no a single solution for your question, all the more so FHIR is not normative yet.

Comment: @user2864740 page is not working. But still this is a confusion. There is no straight  one to one mapping available for CCDA to FHIR

Comment: Thanks. Here is an updated link ([A comparison of two Detailed Clinical Model representations:
FHIR and CDA](https://www.ejbi.org/scholarly-articles/a-comparison-of-two-detailed-clinical-model-representationsfhir-and-cda.pdf)): "Conclusion: Our research shows that possible loss and
change of meaning and lack of interconvertibility occurs
when implementing two separate technical standards based
on the same [Detailed Clinical Models]."

Comment: @user2864740 appreciate it thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, C-CDA is consolidated CDA. It is an IG - Implementation Guide.
In simple terms, there are various IG for generating a CDA document HITSP/C83 for one is an example and there are several others. The main problem with all these seperate IG is that they are not uniform. C-CDA was created to bring uniformity of data. [This presentation here](http://www.healthit.gov/sites/default/files/c-cda_and_meaningfulusecertification.pdf) is a good place to start. Basically, it says you got to have at least 4 mandatory section in your CCD, and rest optional sections. It entirely depends on your use case.

Secondly, You need to download a copy of a valid C-CDA file from [this site](http://sitenv.org/c-cda-validator). Let's take inpatient summary document.
So that would be your target document, and consider it as a template.

Third, You got to tell your engineering team or if you are the developer yourself, then you need to build logic to extract and place information into that template. This is an iterative process, and everytime you need to validate your developed document, against the validator (site given above).

Until and unless the validator says 0 errors present, your document is not ready.

So, There does not exist a ready made code or logic that you can just plug and play and start developing C-CDA documents.

Comment: Hi Sid,
I Have experience in developing CCDA documents, It's tough to build a CCDA from any of the given documents. But now, the problem is the Healthcare is movin towards the development of CCDA to FHIR, as CCDA is complex containing many details and informations making it complex to parse through Interfaces, I'm wondering about the possibility of converting a complete CCDA to as (user3005941) specified resources in FHIR.  Can you enlight me on this part?. like. how and what can I do with FHIR?, and what if there is a need to convert CCDA to FHIR? which I fear may happen any time soon.

Comment: @Vibin, I understand what you are after, but you are not listening to us. What we are telling you is that CDA templates are so diverse that there are no single answer. It would be no FHIR if (C)CDA would be that straightforward.